# Elliptical gradient in SVG

Tags: web, graphics, svg, gradient, ellipse

Is there a way to make an elliptical gradient in SVG?

I tried the suggested code below, but it just displays a red ellipse, not a gradient:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20001102//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-SVG-20001102/DTD/svg-20001102.dtd">

<svg width="100%" height="100%" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" >

  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="gradientDefinition"
      gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop stop-color="yellow" offset="0%" />
      <stop stop-color="red" offset="100%" />
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>

  <ellipse cx="250" cy="150" rx="200" ry="100" stroke="white"
    stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="1 1 1 1"
    style="fill:url(#gradientDefinition)" />
</svg>
```

I want an elliptical gradient, not a circular gradient inside an ellipse.

Comment: Which browser are you using? (When [running](http://jsfiddle.net/6dSM6/) this in Chrome I can see a gradient in the image...)

Comment: @summea I have tried it in Firefox and Inkscape.

Comment: The link in the comment works for me with Firefox.

Comment: @Tyler Which version of Firefox are you using? I've tried it in Firefox 25.0.1 and it works when I add in a `viewBox="0 0 640 480"` parameter inside the `<svg>` tag (though the viewBox dimensions could be whatever you need them to be... and that parameter might not be necessary if it works for someone else in Firefox already...)

Comment: The link above is jsFiddle, not the pure svg file. I confirm that with the viewBox parameter I get a gradient, however the gradient is a circular (radial) gradient, not an elliptical gradient.

Comment: Sorry for misreading the last line in your original post; what about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6dSM6/1/) (i.e. what happens if you take out the `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` attribute/value?) Though, it may still just be a circular gradient... apologies if so.

Comment: It may be that SVG just doesn't have the ability to make an elliptical gradient, although possibly by using a skew or filter it could be approximated.

Comment: Could be; how did the gradient look on that updated jsFiddle in the second to last comment?

Comment: @summea It looks much more elliptical when that parameter is removed, so maybe that is the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize the findings from earlier, it appears that removing the `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` *attribute* and *value* pair from the `<radialGradient>` tag allows for the radial gradient to become (or at least appear to become) elliptical in shape. Also, adding `stop-opacity` attributes and values to each `<stop>` tag allows for the elliptical gradient effect to be more easily seen (at least for demonstration purposes.)

Here is the code with the above changes made:

```
<defs>
    <radialGradient id="gradientDefinition" >
        <stop stop-color="yellow" offset="0%" stop-opacity="0" />
        <stop stop-color="red" offset="100%" stop-opacity="1" />
    </radialGradient>
</defs>
```

To show that this code appears to work:

*see:* [elliptical `radialGradient`](http://jsfiddle.net/6dSM6/10/) **vs** [circular `radialGradient`](http://jsfiddle.net/6dSM6/11/)

There is also a [tutorial online](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_svg.htm) that appears to provide similar behavior for a similar elliptical gradient approach and the results from that tutorial can be found in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dSM6/4/).

*Note: If this approach does not work for your purposes, there may be some other, better approach (possibly having to do with [gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/gradientTransform) [transformations](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#TransformAttribute), or something similar...)*